# How can this MP4 be played in Firefox? From what I know Firefox doesn't support MP4

Tags: firefox, mp4, codec

I found this mp4 from the site Giphy. To my surprise it plays in Firefox. Does anyone know how that can be? Normally I have to generate two versions of every video file, mp4 and webm. It would be nice to not have to do that.

Here's the file:
http://media2.giphy.com/media/yoJC2NG0MLnSoEPjIA/giphy.mp4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox will use an mp4 library is a suitable one is on the system that Firefox is running on:

> Firefox/Firefox for Android/Firefox OS supports the format in some cases, but only when a third-party decoder is available, and the device hardware can handle the profile used to encode the MP4.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats)

Comment: So what you say is that Firefox uses some decoder installed on my computer, a visitor without a mp4 decoder installed will not be able to play it?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use HTML5 I'd suggest the video tag like the following. I figured you'd want controls so I added the controls attribute to the video tag; you could also add autoplay if you want that. I tested it on IE11 and the current versions of Firefox and Chrome. works for all of those. Having alternate versions isn't a bad idea, but mp4 is pretty universal on modern browsers.

```html
<video controls>
      <source src="http://media2.giphy.com/media/yoJC2NG0MLnSoEPjIA/giphy.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="http://media2.giphy.com/media/yoJC2NG0MLnSoEPjIA/giphy.webm" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

As to why:

> MP4 H.264 (AAC or MP3) The MP4 container format with the H.264 video
>   codec and the AAC audio codec is natively supported by desktop/mobile
>   Internet Explorer, Safari and Chrome, but Chromium and Opera do not
>   support the format. IE and Chrome also support the MP3 audio codec in
>   the MP4 container, but Safari does not. Firefox/Firefox for
>   Android/Firefox OS supports the format in some cases, but only when a
>   third-party decoder is available, and the device hardware can handle
>   the profile used to encode the MP4.
>
> Note: MP4s encoded with a high profile will not run on lower end
>   hardware, such as low end Firefox OS phones. The MPEG media formats
>   are covered by patents, which are not freely licensed. All the
>   necessary licenses can be bought from MPEG LA. Since H.264 is
>   currently not a royalty free format, it is unfit for the open web
>   platform, according to Mozilla [1, 2], Google [1, 2] and Opera.
>   However, since royalty free formats are not supported by Internet
>   Explorer and Safari, Mozilla has decided to support the format anyway,
>   and Google never fulfilled their promise to remove support for it in
>   Chrome.
>   
> Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: Ah no I don't mean how to play it. The thing is that Firefox shouldn't be able to play MP4 since its not supported. But it can for some reason play this.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 and it works, my colleague uses Mac and it worked there as well.